# Woocommerce: How to set fixed stock quantity for all products once, with php

Tags: php, woocommerce, stock

How can i  set a fixed quantity to **all** of the store products on my **woocommerce** website? I want to change **all of the products quantity** to 1 once, without  the need to change all the products quantity one by one.

**Note:** Yes, i want to set  a fixed quantity on all products but i should be able to remove the stock management on specific products. Eg when i untick `Manage stock` option on the product woocommerce edit page that product should not have quantity.

this is what i have tried to the following path `line 157` without success:

Path: `woocommerce\includes\class-wc-cart-totals.php`

```
    tax_class'          => '',
    'taxable'            => false,
    'quantity'           => 1, //changed to 1 from 0
    'product'            => false,
    'price_includes_tax' => false,
```

Comment: Yes, why not? Add more details, some code that you have tried so far to get detailed answers.

Comment: @VivekAthalye i have a simple question and i want a simple answer. Who said i want a detailed answer?

Comment: Sorry if my prev comment sounded rude. But I'm really not sure abt ur requirement. Like: do u want to set it only once, or do you want it to remain constant irrespective of how many items are sold? In either case u may want to show the code that you have tried so that ppl can help you in resolving any issue in that code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @VivekAthalye yes i want to set the quantity of all of the product to 1 once. Then if i want to i can change it back to 1 or 2 or whatever

Comment: This plugin https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-fixed-quantity/ doesn´t help you?

Comment: @ArturSonnenhohl no i want to change the quantity on ALL products of the website to 1. My question is clear

Comment: @csandreas1 i think the easiest will be a simple query.

Comment: yes the code should also have an if statement, when untick the `Manage stock` option, the stock quantity on that specific product should be removed. So yes, i want to put on all product a fix quantity but i should be able to remove the stock quantity on specific products